# Compress files with logrotate

Tags: linux, unix, logrotate

I have a directory structure which contains files already rotated (eg. there is a date part applied to the end). I would like to compress them and keep only 7 of each file type.

Is this achievable with logrotate?

Comment: Yes - did you read the man page which includes examples of how to achieve these results?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the `compress` option to your logrotate config file? Reinventing the wheel sucks.

Answer (score -2):

I have decided to write a shell script instead of using logrotate for this purpose.